# Excel 2007 - Time exceeding 24 hours where [h]:mm doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm building a spreadsheet to calculate aircraft flying hours which will exceed 24. I am aware of the [h]:mm format to force Excel to not use units of days.

I want to set a threshold number of hours which I will subtract a running total from. However with the [h]:mm format set if I enter 1 in the cell, for 1:00, instead it interprets it as 24:00 - one day.

How can I avoid this, so that I can do simple arithmetic with hours and minutes exceeding a 24 hour period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type  `1:0` or even just `1:` instead of just `1`

If you type `1` excel interprets this as the value 1, which is date serial value to 1 day (actually 1/1/1900)

If you type something that looks like a time (eg contains a :) then excel interprets it as a string representation of a time and converts it to the corresponding serial value (0.041666667 or 1/24) and applies the format so it displays as 1:00